# Rotate view controller not in view in tab bar app

Tags: ios, rotation

I have a tab bar application. Rotation is fine on every view controller.

I'm in landscape, if I go to view controller B and rotate to portrait, then go back to view controller A, A's view hasn't been rotated - as it didn't get the events - so the UI is all out of proportation and I need to rotate the device to sort it out. Not good.

I could listen for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, but I don't want to manually call the rotation methods (willRotate, willAnimate, didRotate)... as this obviously is fragile.

What am I missing to get this working correctly?

Comment: Can you share some code for more information? Did you subclass the tabBar?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that my views had code that needed to run on rotation, which only happened in the rotation notification methods.

The way I solved this was:

```
 - (void) deviceOrientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (self.isViewLoaded && !self.view.window) {
        // viewController view is loaded, but not visible
        [self viewDidRotateOffscreen];
    }
 }
```

1. The code inside the willRotate, willAnimate, didRotate was pulled into a separate method.
2. I listened for UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, and set a BOOL flag viewDidRotateOffscreen (see code above)
3. On viewWillAppear, I check the BOOL flag viewDidRotateOffscreen, and if it's true, I run the method that I just mentioned in step 1.